# MySQL - How do I order based on columns from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables:

Table 'Data':

```
| Customer | Category | Brand | Market | A | B |
|==========|==========|=======|========|===|===|
| Bill     | 5        | 4     |1       |2  |9  |
| Bill     | 5        | 4     |1       |6  |15 |
| Bill     | 5        | 4     |1       |1  |30 |
| Greg     | 7        | 9     |3       |5  |1  |
| Amy      | 9        | 2     |1       |1  |8  |
```

Table 'Customer':

```
| Cust | Mkt | SubMkt |
|======|=====|========|
| Bill | 1   | NY     |
| Bill | 2   | Arizona|
| Bill | 3   | Cali   |
| Greg | 1   | Ohio   |
| Amy  | 1   | Texas  |
```

Table 'Sort':

```
| SubMarket | SortBy |
|===========|========|
| Cali      | A      |
| Ohio      | B      |
| Arizona   | A      |
| NY        | A      |
```

I need to select all from 'Data' ordered by a few different columns and then either A or B depending on what 2 other tables say.

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
ORDER BY Customer, Category, Brand, Market, (A or B)
```

Basically, `Customer` **and** `Market` in table `Data` links to `Cust` **and** `Mkt` in table `Customer`, and then `SubMkt` in table `Customer` links to `SubMarket` in table `Sort`.  Then `SortBy` in table `Sort` would be the column I need to sort by in table `Data`.  Hope that makes sense.

So, in the above example, all of the rows in `Data` containing both "Bill" for `Customer` and "1" for `Market` would be sorted by column `A`.

I started to write an array of objects in PHP and then I would sort the array based on an object property but this would actually require a huge overhaul on my existing code.  I assume what I'm looking for can be done with a fairly straight forward query in MySQL but I don't know MySQL well enough to write that query.   Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:  I should have mentioned, these are just partial tables.  The actual tables I'm working with are thousands of rows and every "SubMarket" does have a matching "SortBy".

Edit 2: Clarified that `Customer` **and** `Market` is needed in table `Data` to link to `Cust` **and** `Mkt` in table `Customer`.

Comment: the issue with this is what do you want to sort the rest of your data by? you have three submarkets that match.. so how should you sort the rest of the data? or do you want to filter it out?

Comment: Sorry, these are just partial tables.  The actually tables I'm working with are thousands of rows.  There is a "SortBy" for every possible "SubMarket".

Comment: so are there any more columns as well than the ones you provided?

Comment: Yes, there are more columns but none that are relevant (that I can tell) to this question.

Comment: if you have a unique id or anything like that you should post that as well.. currently you have no way to join the two tables together without getting data integrity issues

Comment: Hmmm...Okay, I may have to go with my original plan of doing it all in PHP then when a big code overhaul.  

"Customer" and "Market" from the table "Data" wouldn't join with "Cust" and "Mkt" from the table "Customer" to find the right "SubMkt"?  and then "SubMkt" joins with "SubMarket" to find the right "SortBy"?  Again, I don't understand joining well enough to know if I'm using the right terminology or not.  

Unfortunately, I don't create these tables.  They are just given to me this way and it's all I have to work with.

Comment: you will have that issue in php as well. there must be a way to link the tables.. especially if it was set up by someone who has been programming for a while. can you post the rest of the fields? i may be able to help :)

Comment: Well, I **know** I'd be able to do it in PHP with the tables as is so perhaps I didn't explain something clear enough in the OP if you think it's also not possible in PHP.

Comment: the issue is when you join two tables if you did it on the name.. you would have multiple duplicated rows because there are more than one bill in both tables.. if you did it on market.. you don't have matching numbers.. so there needs to be another column that matches the two.. like a column with a 1 for the first row on both tables

Comment: Yes, you found the issue in my original post, I see exactly what you're saying.  I edited it to clarify.  Customer and Market is needed in table Data to link to Cust and Mkt in table Customer.  Does that make sense?  Does that solve the issue?

Comment: i just saw your edit.. if thats the case then your post is missing data.. greg wouldn't be joined because the data doesn't match.. but I understand what youre saying.. let me see if I can write up an answer real quick

Comment: Yeah, again, this is just partial data to give the gist of what I'm looking for.  I think I added enough data for Bill so you can see how each links and eventually determines that the "Bill" rows in Data need to be ordered by column A.  Sorry, I should have been much more thoughtful in the example tables I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just an answer showing how to do the joins.. Ignacio should have the accepted answer as he provided the hard part first :)

```
SELECT d.*
FROM data d
JOIN customers c on c.cust = d.customer AND c.mkt = d.market
JOIN sort s on s.submarket = c.submkt
ORDER BY 
    d.Customer, 
    d.Category, 
    d.Brand,  
    d.Market, 
    CASE s.sortby
        WHEN 'A' THEN d.A
        WHEN 'B' THEN d.B
        ELSE 9999999
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`CASE` expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).

```
CASE `Sort`.`SortBy`
  WHEN "A" THEN `Data`.`A`
  WHEN "B" THEN `Data`.`B`
  ELSE NULL
END CASE
```

The `ELSE NULL` part is optional, but it can help reveal data problems.

Comment: Where does the table 'Customer' come into play here?  I think you're assuming I understand MySQL much better than I actually do.  I get lost when it comes to joins or unions which I'm assuming are needed.  Simply 
`SELECT *

FROM Data
ORDER BY Customer, Category, Brand, Market, 
CASE \`Sort\`.\`SortBy\`
  WHEN "A" THEN \`Data\`.\`A\`
  WHEN "B" THEN \`Data\`.\`B\`
  ELSE NULL
END CASE`

won't do it, will it?

Comment: @JackHillard you have to join the tables. the issue is what on? you seem to have a flawed database design